# Adding loop results as rows in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

I am trying to make this `for` loop print the results as respective rows of the same dataframe. I tried this code but it doesn't seem to be working.  It is giving an index error right now because it outputs separate empty dataframes for each iteration.

```
list2=[(('ATM',), ('ROA',)), (('ATM',), ('ROE',)), (('ATM',), ('NIM',)), (('ATM',), ('ROA', 'ROE')), (('ATM',), ('ROA', 'NIM'))]
tm_final = {0: 3, 1: 6, 2: 4, 3: 2, 4: 0}
totalrows=sum(tm_final[i]>0 for i in tm_final)
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C'])
for i in tm_final:
  if tm_final[i]>0:
    for j in range(totalrows):
      df.iloc[j,0]=i
      df.iloc[j,1]=str(list2[i])
      df.iloc[j,2]=tm_final[i]
    print(df)
```

Desired result:

```
   A                B                             C
   0  (('ATM',), ('ROA',))                        3
   1  (('ATM',), ('ROE',))                        6
   2  (('ATM',), ('NIM',))                        4
   3  (('ATM',), ('ROA', 'ROE'))                  2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a better way to go about it, posting it here.

```
list2=[(('ATM',), ('ROA',)), (('ATM',), ('ROE',)), (('ATM',), ('NIM',)), (('ATM',), 
('ROA', 'ROE')), (('ATM',), ('ROA', 'NIM'))]
tm_final = {0: 3, 1: 6, 2: 4, 3: 2, 4: 0}
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C'])

for i in tm_final:
  if tm_final[i]>0:
      df=df.append({'A':i,'B':list2[i],'C':tm_final[i]},ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tm_final = {key: value for (key, value) in tm_final.items() if value > 0 }
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C'])
df.A = tm_final.keys()
df.B = list2
df.C = tm_final.values()
df
   A                     B  C
0  0      ((ATM,), (ROA,))  3
1  1      ((ATM,), (ROE,))  6
2  2      ((ATM,), (NIM,))  4
3  3  ((ATM,), (ROA, ROE))  2
```

Comment: No, please check the `if` condition, it won't print any row for the 5th iteration because it doesn't satisfy the condition. Your code doesn't solve the problem

Comment: please check the code again. i missed the first line. Thanks

Comment: The condition also needs to be put on `list2`

Comment: can you be a bit specific on teh requirement, as the `list2` has 5 items, `tm_final` has 4 now